# In jQuery UI Autocomplete, where does the `response` function is implemented?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am pretty new in JS and in jQuery. In my work I came across a jQuery code from the jQuery UI Autocomplete widget that I do not fully understand. I have a two questions about this code which are separated into several posts (As recommended in [that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/39224) meta post). Also, sorry if my English is horrible, I'm doing my best. :)

Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/NyG48Yb9

**What I DO understand:**

- The `autocomplete` function operates on some `input`, in our case - the `#searchBox`. The function get as parameter an object that represents the behavior of the list when the user types into the `#searchBox`.
- The object has a key named `source` which describes the resource that provides the list.

**What I DO NOT understand #1:**
The value of the `source` key is a callback function that gets two parameters: `request` and `response`. According to the [jQuery UI Autocomplete API Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source), the second parameter is:

> A response callback

which means that it is a function. Now, according to [that](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/) tutorial about callback functions (Yeah, I did some research :D) there is a function A and a function B. Function A gets as a parmeter a variable that contains a reference to a function that is specified to be function B when we call function A, and function B is executed in the scope of function A.

In my code, function A is the anonymous function in the `source` key, and the `response` is the callback function. But I cannot find any implementation of the `response` function.

**My question:**
Where does the `response` function is implemented? And where can I fine a documentation?

Thank you very much. :)

---

My other question: [In jQuery UI Autocomplete, what data sources can the `source` key hold?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32143422/in-jquery-ui-autocomplete-what-data-sources-can-the-source-key-hold)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of `response` is present in jquery-ui.js. Its their internal function. To know its implementation you will have to download uncompressed jquery-ui.js and will have to locate `autocomplete` related code.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain to me what that function does? I couldn't find an answer to that.

Comment: Hello Sipo. In general the `response` callback function do following things: 1) read the suggestions array prepared by us. For example in your case, it reads the `resp` JS array which you have prepared via Ajax call. 2) iterate over it and prepare HTML DOM structure so that the suggestions are visible to end user. 3) internally it attaches click/select event to each suggestions list element so that whenever user selects any suggestion from autocomplete suggestion list; its handler like `select:` gets executed.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is exactly what I needed.