# In jQuery UI Autocomplete, what data sources can the `source` key hold?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am pretty new in JS and in jQuery. In my work I came across a jQuery code from the jQuery UI Autocomplete widget that I do not fully understand. I have a two questions about this code which are separated into several posts (As recommended in [that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/39224) meta post). Also, sorry if my English is horrible, I'm doing my best. :)

Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/NyG48Yb9

**What I DO understand:**

- The `autocomplete` function operates on some `input`, in our case - the `#searchBox`. The function get as parameter an object that represents the behavior of the list when the user types into the `#searchBox`.
- The object has a key named `source` which describes the resource that provides the list.

**What I DO NOT understand #2:**
The value of the `source` key, in this case - is a callback function that according to the [jQuery UI Autocomplete API Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source), is:

> The third variation, a callback, provides the most flexibility and can be used to connect any data source to Autocomplete.

**My question**
What kind of data source is included in "any data source"? `string`, `Array`, `Object`?  A remote resource that provides a JSON using Ajax? Other? Can you give me an example?

Thank you very much. :)

---

My other question: [In jQuery UI Autocomplete, where does the `response` function is implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32141272/in-jquery-ui-accordion-what-data-sources-can-the-source-key-hold)

Comment: In short, data source can be asynchronous (think of AJAX) so `source` function cannot simply return a value. Instead, when data is ready, it has to call `response` function (provided as argument) with actual data. Data itself can be array of strings or array of objects with `label` and `value` properties. For example, AJAX call may be placed within `source` function and `response` called from `done` handler. There are many examples, maybe you will find [this post](http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2013/12/jquery-ui-autocomplete-examples.html) useful.